# Div opacity=0 only when I type something in text-field

Tags: html, opacity

I have a text field and an explaining div. Can I make this explaining div have opacity = 0 ONLY when I type something in the text field? 
Thanks in advance for any help. 
Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type='text' name='input' id="searchdevice" class="search-field"  placeholder="" autofocus/>

<div id="explain">
            Search your device in the text field
            </div>
```

Comment: You want the opacity to be zero if someone is typing, when someone has typed or in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just CSS if you set the input as `required`:

```html
<input type='text' name='input' id='searchdevice' class='search-field' required='required' autofocus />

<div id='explain'>
    Search your device in the text field
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Show by default */
#explain {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Hide it when input field has content */
#searchdevice:valid + #explain {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Remove "invalid" styling when input field is empty.
E.g. in Firefox, the input has a red box-shadow by default. */
#searchdevice:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

When you type something in the input field, it's "valid" and the `#explain` will have opacity of 0.

Browser support for the `:valid` selector: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2ozh40vp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('#searchdevice').on('input', function(){
    $('#explain').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

Comment: You should add more explanation to your answer.  What does this code do?  How does it answer the question?  Why would OP try this instead of the original code or any of the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

This will require JavaScript to listen to text input and hide the DIV.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#searchdevice').on('input', function(){
    $('#explain').addClass('hidden');
});
```

css:

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/kphgg2d0/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, javascript is good here though, functionality is kept where it belongs, responding to events in css is questionable practice. You'll want the **keypress event** for typing. The functions defined separately makes them easier to re-use.

```
var hideExplain = function() {
    document.getElementById('explain').style.opacity='0';
}

document.getElementById('searchdevice').addEventListener("keypress", hideExplain);
```

[see keypress example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpttwhk/)

You might be better doing this though, as **focus and blur** will allow you to undo the effect when the user moves on. There's a show function included here too.

```
var showExplain = function() {
    document.getElementById('explain').style.opacity='1';
}

document.getElementById('searchdevice').addEventListener("focus", hideExplain);
document.getElementById('searchdevice').addEventListener("blur", showExplain);
```

[see the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpttwhk/3/)

You could use keypress to remove the tip and blur to reshow it, that way the tip would hang around for as long as possible for the user. [See anothe example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpttwhk/5/)

Also, you would find it better **to add and remove classes** - here's an example with JQuery. Now your style classes are re-usable too.

CSS

```
.is-transparent {
    opacity: 0;
}

.is-opaque {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#explain').removeClass('is-opaque').addClass('is-transparent');
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need this css line:

```
input:focus + #explain{opacity:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kLLkyvyh/

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#searchdevice').blur(function(){
                $('#explain').fadeTo(1000, 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' name='input' id="searchdevice" class="search-field" placeholder="" autofocus/>
<div id="explain">Search your device in the text field</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can try various effects through `fadeto` from the link - http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/